# Mean of maximum of exponential random variables (independent but not identical)

Tags: mean, order-statistics, extreme-value, exponential-distribution

I am looking for the the mean of the maximum of N independent but not identical exponential random variables. I found the CDF and the pdf but I couldn't compute the integral to find the mean of the maximum.

The CDF : $ \mathbf{F_{X_{max}}}(x)= \prod_{k=1}^{K} (1-exp(-\lambda_k x)) $ and
The pdf is  : $ \mathbf{f_{X_{max}}}(x)= \sum_{k=1}^{K}\lambda_k exp(-\lambda_k x) \prod_{q=1,q\neq k}^{K} (1-exp(-\lambda_q x)) $
so the mean that I am trying to find is : 
 $ \mathbb{E} [X_{max}] = \int_{0}^{\infty} x \mathbf{f_{X_{max}}}(x) dx $

Comment: Could you write down the integral you have to evaluate?

Comment: Do you have some restrictions on the parameters of the exponential?

Comment: I added the expression of the integral.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by restrictions on the exponentials parameters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/642021/348271) for expectation of positive random variables in terms of the survival function and expanding the product in your formula for the cdf,
\begin{align}
EX_\text{max}
  &=\int_0^\infty P(X_\text{max}>x)dx
\\&=\int_0^\infty1-\prod_{i=1}^n(1-e^{-\lambda_i x})dx
\\&=\sum_{S\subseteq\{1,2,\dots,n\}}(-1)^{|S|} \int_0^\infty e^{-x\sum_{j\in S}\lambda_j}dx
\\&=\sum_{S\subseteq\{1,2,\dots,n\}}(-1)^{|S|-1} \frac1{\sum_{j\in S}\lambda_j},
\end{align}
where the outer sum is over all non-empty subsets $S$ of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and $|S|$ denotes the number of elements of $S$.

So for $n=1$, this simplifies to the usual formula
$$
E X_\text{max} = \frac1{\lambda_1},
$$
for $n=2$, 
$$
E X_\text{max} = \frac1{\lambda_1} + \frac1{\lambda_2} - \frac1{\lambda_1+\lambda_2},
$$
for $n=3$,
$$
E X_\text{max} = \frac1{\lambda_1} + \frac1{\lambda_2} + \frac1{\lambda_3} - \frac1{\lambda_1+\lambda_2} - \frac1{\lambda_1+\lambda_3} - \frac1{\lambda_2+\lambda_3} + \frac1{\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3},
$$
and so on.

Comment: Sorry this is not an answer, but a question to @Jarle for some clarification
I understand that there was a conversion between F(x) and S(x) between the two lines.
And the exponent changed to summation of lambda's
But can you please elaborate on the outer summation here, what rules were applied to get from line 1 to line 2 ? [![product to summation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8oCZ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8oCZ.png)

Comment: It's just expanding the product:  $(1-a)(1-b)=1-a-b+ab$